# Правильно ли расставлены запятые в этих предложениях?

Tags: пунктуация, как

Что было самым главным для Вас, как для руководителя крупнейшего производителя газовой арматуры, за эти полтора года?

Для меня, как для руководителя, этот период не был слишком трудным.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Что было самым главным для Вас, **как для руководителя крупнейшего производителя газовой арматуры**, за эти полтора года?

Для меня **как для руководителя** этот период не был слишком трудным.

Здесь в обоих случаях оборот имеет **значение "в качестве",** а не причинное значение, поэтому **обособление  в общем случае не требуется.** Но в первом предложении можно обособить оборот **в связи с его распространенностью** ( распространенное обстоятельство со значением уточнения).

Примечание (почему нет причинного значения)

Нельзя сказать: Что было самым главным для Вас, так как Вы являетесь руководителем крупнейшего производителя газовой арматуры, за эти полтора года?

Comment: Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

Ну да, запятые нужны. Здесь явно причинное значение. Ну или в значении "будучи" - тут уж как трактовать, но в обоих случая запятые нужны.

Значения  "в качестве" я здесь рассмотреть не могу, хотя, возможно, кто-то и увидит.

А в чем сомнения, Alenka? Здесь возможны варианты, если автор по-своему понимает смысл написанного. Но это только сам автор может сказать. А вообще-то http://www.gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_183

Comment: Обороты с **как** у меня по-прежнему вызывают сомнения... А тренироваться, да, надо...

Comment: Ну так вы пишите, что сомневаетесь, как трактовать - или та не знаете правила... Обороты с "как" вообще узкое место, так что ничего зазорного, но хоть понятно, в чем затруднения.